# Why aren't my anchor tags functioning on GitHub?

Tags: html

I assume that when I upload a repository, only one file is displayed on the site, and the other files are just sitting there in the folder, waiting to be accessed by the anchor tag. Instead, when I try to click one of the anchor tags hosted on GitHub, it leads to a 404 error. Do I have to make a repository for EACH of my **.html** files even if they're in the same folder? This sounds very insufficient, I believe there is another way to go about this that I don't know of.

On my main **index.html** file, I included anchor tags that direct the user to another section of the site with this:

```
<a href="/dashboard.html">Dashboard</a>
```

I can already see why this doesn't work but I don't know how to fix it. So I just ended up with this:

```
<a href="basic-website/dashboard.html">Dashboard</a>
```

I added basic-website because that was the name of my repository. Sadly, it didn't work. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean GitHub Pages and not GitHub.

If your repo is named *basic-website* then the URL to the top level of the repo will be  `https://example.github.io/basic-website/`.

This means that *dashboard.html* will have the URL `https://example.github.io/basic-website/dashboard.html`.

---

If you link from `https://example.github.io/basic-website/` to `/dashboard.html` then you get `https://example.github.io/dashboard.html`. Which is wrong. `basic-website` is missing.

If you link from `https://example.github.io/basic-website/` to `basic-website/dashboard.html` then you get `https://example.github.io/basic-website/dashboard.html`. Which is wrong. `basic-website` is there too many times.

---

Just link to `dashboard.html`.

Don't put a `/` to go up to the root of the site.

Don't put a directory to go down into when you are already in that directory.